# POI, Point of Interest - український відповідник

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни, іншомовні-слова

Вже певний час не можу для себе винайти відповідь, як саме перекласти для використання, як в *програмному забезпеченні для навігації*, так і для повсякденного використання термін **Point of Interest** та його скорочення **POI**.

Цим терміном визначають певні об'єкти, що можуть зацікавити користувача на місцевості. Це можуть бути як магазини, лікарні, будь-які установи так і об'єкти інфраструктури - пожежні гідранти, поштові скрині й таке інше.

Туристичні довідники та каталоги можуть містити описи цікавих місць та розваг, на які варто звернути увагу – це також Point of Interest.

Поруч з цим також часто можна зустріти інший споріднений термін **Area of Interest, AOI** – територія що може цікавити як сама по собі, так і місце де знаходяться інші POI.

Comment: «Англійсько-українсько-англійський словник наукової мови (фізика та споріднені науки)» Кочерги й Мейнаровича (2010) [перекладає](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=point+of+interest&dicts=4&highlight=on&filter_lines=on) _point of interest_ як _дослі́джувана [розгля́дувана] то́чка_, _обгово́рювана пробле́ма_ — але, здається, це не підходить (зовсім інший контекст). У вікіпедії ніяк не переклали — [«POI»](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/POI).

Comment: Бачив варіант перекладу (не українською, але у контексті навігації) "корисне місце".

Comment: Як на мене основна проблема в тому, що в українській мові відсутнє саме поняття, яке б могло передавати сенс цього терміну. Так, наприклад, аптека або лікарня –  можуть бути цікавими для вас, коли вони вам потрібні. В загальному сенсі в них немає нічого цікавого. В них є "користь", але таки ж знов, тільки у відповідному контексті вживання. Мурал, пам'ятник вже важко назвати "корисним місцем". 
Продовжую пошуки, сподіваюсь на допомогу спільноти.

Answer (score 4):

У [тлумачному словнику](http://sum.in.ua/s/interes) можна побачити що слово "інтерес" має досить широке значення (цікавий приклад до третього значення, що пов'яюзує інтерес і кав'ярню):

> 1. Увага до кого-, чого-небудь, зацікавлення кимось, чимось.
> 2. Вага, значення.
> 3. перев. мн. Те, що найбільше цікавить кого-небудь, що становить зміст чиїхось думок і турбот; прагнення, потреби. ***Кав'ярня*** була серцем села, куди збігались усі інтереси людності (Михайло Коцюбинський)
> 4. перев. мн. Те, що йде на користь кому-, чому-небудь, відповідає чиїмсь прагненням, потребам.

Тому, як на мене, слово "інтерес" у своїх різних значеннях може бути використане і до "цікавого місця" як туристичного об'єкту, і до "корисного" як автозаправка. Тому "точка інтересу" має право на існування.

Пошуки прикладів використання дають декілька областей знань, де використовують термін "точка інтересу" - навігація, туризм, комп'ютерний зір:

- Туризм - сайт ["Херсон Daily"](https://khersondaily.com/news/hersonschina---tochka-interesu): "завершується робота щодо розробки збірки вело та пішохідних туристичних маршрутів Херсонщиною «Херсонщина – **точка інтересу**»"
- Навігація - [сайт Lexus](https://www.lexus.ua/multimedia/onboarding/cy17/search-for-a-poi-point-of-interest), інструкція з користування навігатором: "Щоб знайти **точки інтересу** (ТІ), перейдіть в головне меню, натиснувши кнопку [МЕНЮ]. Перейдіть в [Місце призначення] та оберіть [Пошук]".
- Комп'ютерний зір - [наукова стаття](http://cad.kpi.ua/attachments/043_2017_07_br.pdf) "Виявлення **точок iнтересу** методом iнтегральних проекцiй"
- Комп'ютерний зір - [наукова стаття](https://conferences.vntu.edu.ua/index.php/mn/mn2019/paper/viewFile/8079/6764) "Виділення рухомих об'єктів цифрових зображень шляхом пошуку **точок інтересу**": "**Точка інтересу** – така точка сцени, зображення околу якої можна відрізнити від зображень околів всіх інших точок сцени. Важливою властивістю точки інтересу об’єкта є її інваріантність до змін освітленості або точки спостереження камери.

Comment: Дуже класна знахідка, як на мене. Взагалі слово інтерес у загальному вжитку хочеться бачити побільше)

Answer (score 3):

**(something) of interest** вказує на предмет дослідження чи обговорення. Залежить від контексту і не має прямого перекладу українською.

Однак, має набір більш розповсюджених визначень, такі як **point of interest** у туризмі, що може означати місця, цікаві для туристів.

**Person of interest** у розмові поліцейських може вказувати на підозрюваного.

**Area of interest** під час аналізу може вказувати на область значень, що містять значення, які є потенціальною відповіддю до вирішуваної задачі (**points of interest**). У точних науках може бути виражене ОДЗ (область допустимих значень).